# Need to render row cells to next line(in continuation) on page ends in itextpdf

Tags: pdf, itext, rendering, rows

Team, I am new to iText PDF tables, and I am trying to do a POC large no of cells on each row.

As part of my requirement, I wants to render the all the cells of the row in continuation(in next line) in lines. But, As per the itext implementation,  cells are that are beyond the page size not rendering.

Can you please helps us to do this.

Comment: Thanks Paulo for your suggestion. I tried it, it is not working as expected. It is more about how to auto render the cells to next line on page size exceeds.

Answer (score 0):

That´s a rather strange table if it can still called a table. You can use `PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows()` to write just the cells you need but you'll have to do your own layout, it's a custom requirement after all.